# How to modify knockout.js observable immediately in computed callback function?

Tags: knockout.js

I'm using knockout.js 3.0 and I'm stuck with some simple conclusion:

```
 var self = this;
 self.selectedItem = ko.observable("default text");
 ko.computed(function () {
    if (this.selectedItem() != "default text") {
       this.selectedItem("success");
    }
 }, self);
```

But when I change my observable, computed callback function is triggering again. So how to prevert it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a writable computed observable like this:

```
var self = this;
self.selectedItem = ko.observable("default text");
self.notifySelectedItem = ko.computed({
  read: self.selectedItem,
  write: function (value) {
    if (this.selectedItem() != "default text") {
      self.selectedItem(value);
      alert("success");
    }
  }
});
```

Use **notifySelectedItem** instead of **selectedItem** wherever you need to be notified about the change. It will display the selectedItem value, and call the write callback on update. You might need to move the self.selectedItem(value) outside the if block, according to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, you assign a variable name to your computed function so it can be referenced from somewhere in your view.  Also computed is not a "callback", that is different thing entirely although a computed could be used as a callback function I suppose.  A ko computed observable is usually an observable that you want to have react to other observables changing although there are many other uses for it.

```
var self = this;
self.selectedItem = ko.observable("default text");
self.testTextChange = ko.computed(function () {
    if (self.selectedItem() != "default text") {
       alert("success"); // Changed this to alert, otherwise, you will change the value of the input as you stated in your question.
    }
});
```

Then in your view, something like

```
<input data-bind="text: selectedItem" />
<button data-bind="click: testTextChange">Click Me</button>
```

This is a completely arbitrary example though, which brings up several questions, what do you have in your view for your `data-bind` and what exactly are you trying to do with this?

Comment: Thanks for reply! I thought I didn't need to have testTextChange variable because in this 'trigger' (is that a good name for it?) function I make ajax request. 
Also there are some other conditions, so it can be the situation when I need to revert changes. Sorry, if I made confusion in my example.. Generally I need to set previous value like 

if (this.selectedItem() != "default text") {
       this.selectedItem("default text");
    }

Answer (score -1):

You seem to be confused about how computed observables are used, since you're not saving the observable on a property of `self` at all.

In any case, you do two things that will cause problems for you when combined:

1. Make the computed depend on the observable `selectedItem`
2. Have the computed *update* `selectedItem`

This will (or at least: *might*) cause an endless loop, because the computed will be recalculated every time the underlying observable changes, but it's changing that observable itself.

Even though you *can*, it's probably not wise to update (observable) variables in a computed observable at all, at least not in the `read` (a.k.a. "getter") version.

PS. You may be looking for [writable computed observables](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html).

Comment: I'm unsure why this answer got downvoted, any tips on what to improve?

Comment: not sure I always need to save computed in a property of self. I'll try to use "setter", thanks

Comment: sorry, but I can't understand what should I do with this.. I tried to implement 'read' and 'write' callback functions, saved computed as model property. Now there is no any observable (means selectedItem), and just computed. But in setter I cant modify computed. I suppose it's not possible, and I'll try to find other solution. (There was idea: add some conditions to prevent loop - not elegant but it can resolve my problem)